# Why did god create us even though he knew that we will partake in adharma?

Tags: dharma

God knows that humans will partake in adharma. So why did he create us?

Comment: We know that God, and the Jivas (souls/living entities which are marginal part and parcel energy of God) and the maya (His material enegy) are all eternal (never created or distroyed)

Here the question should be, why has God created/manifested material system when He was aware that humans will partake in adharma to maintain their livelihoods in the world of temporary things? (Hint: The Bh.Gita verse #7.27).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's see this the way Tantra talks about it. [Shiva Sutras, Introduction part, Page xix](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf),

> The God is nothing but Ultimate Reality, also termed as *chit* or *Parasamvit*. It is non-relational consciousness. It is the changeless principle of all changes. In it there is no distinction between subject and object, Of I and This. It is supreme self surviving Itself.

So question is, why it needs to change, why can't he stay at his real state forever and why to create all the creatures ?

The answer is simple.

It is *svabhava* the very nature of Ultimate Reality to manifest. Creativity is of the very essence of Divinity. If Ultimate Reality did not manifest, it would not be self or consciousness, but not-Self, something like a jar.

As Acharya Abhinavagupta puts it,

> अस्थास्यदेकरूपेण वपुषा चेन्महेश्वर: ||
>
> महेश्वरत्वं संवित्वम तदत्यक्षद् घटादिवत् ||

*"If the Highest Reality did not manifest in infinite variety, but reminded cooped up within its solid, singleness, it would neither be the Highest Power nor Consciousness, but something like a jar"*

Comment: Although I have voted to close the question. Ideally the referenced question should have been closed because this question was asked in prior to that.

Answer (score 8):

Strictly speaking no one can answer this question. It is God's sweet will.

Two reasons are given in Hindu scripture.

> In the beginning, this universe was verily the self in the form of a
> person. He pondered and beheld nothing but himself. He first said, ‘I
> am he’. Therefore he got the name ‘I’. Hence even now when any one is
> accosted, he first says, ‘It is I’, and then tells the other name that
> he has. Because he was the first (among the aspirants to the status of
> Prajapati), and (before) this whole group consumed all evils,
> therefore he is called Purusa. He who knows thus verily consumes him
> who wishes to be (Prajapati) in advance of him.

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad I.4.1

> He was frightened. Therefore one is (still) frightened when one is
> alone. He reflected, ‘Since there is nothing besides myself, what am
> I afraid of?’ From that alone his fear departed, for what should he be
> afraid of? Fear comes from only a second entity.

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad I.4.2

> **Verily he did not feel happy. Therefore one (still) does not feel
> happy when alone. He desired a mate.** He became of the size of a man
> and wife embracing each other. He divided this very body into two.
> From that husband and wife came into being. ‘Therefore this body (of
> a man) is one-half of himself, like half of a two-celled seed’, so
> said Yajnavalkya. Hence this void is verily filled by the wife. He
> united with her. From that men were born.

Brhadaranyaka Upanishad I.4.3

Prajapati is the first manifestation of the Divine and becomes the whole of the universe. The Upanishad suggests that the universe and all its living beings were manifested because Prajapati or God felt lonely.

Another reason is that the universe is simply a lila or sport.

**On Lila**

> The Supreme Spirit, being approached (at His behest) by His own subtle
> Divine Power (Prakrti, Universal Nature), constituted of the three
> Gunas (Dispositions called Sattva, Rajas and Tamas), looked at her
> **sportively**, as it were, and thereby endowed her with the power of
> world evolution by impregnating her with his own emanation as the Jiva
> or the individual spirit.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.26.4**

There is also a verse in Brahma Sutra that talks of the universe as the pastime of Brahman.

> But (creation for Brahman is) a mere pastime like what is seen in the
> world.

**Brahma Sutra II.1.33 of Sri Sankaracharya translated by Swami Gambhirananda**

Comment: Apparently God was also an extrovert .

Comment: In other words, human beings are a way for the Universe to know Himself. Since God is omniscient, then all ways of knowing must come to exist & be experienced.

Comment: why do god felt lonely.. when is poorna, indicated poornamidham, poornath  mudchayathe sloka.. is your translation is correctly? i have question if it meant the opposite of what you have said @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately no one can give an answer to this question!

Comment: why dont you ask god?@PradipGangopadhyay