# Did our scriptures mention any avatar that Parabrahma has taken?

Tags: avatars

We know Lord Vishnu's avatars and we mostly have knowledge of different forms of deities and their leela. But does our scriptures have any accounts of avatars of Parabrahma?

Comment: According to Tantra, Parabrahma manifests to many. So if avatar means taking birth in this world as any being, then answer is yes. Check this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26072/647 However I want to know as per you what kinda of avatar you're referring to ?

Comment: Similar to Lord Vishnu's avatars to uplift the conditioned souls. Wasn't Lord Krishna avatar of parabrahma? His lifestyle behavior and the way he discoursed Gita, looks Krishna must be avatar of Para-brahma though no scripture support is available.

Comment: Looks there are some hidden knowledge of Parabrahma, and looks those knowledge will be awarded only to qualified souls!

Comment: According to Tantra, everyone is Parabrahma, Be it Krishna or Rama or you or me or others.

Comment: Can you quote specific reference?

Comment: I shared one link in one of my comment. Check once. I can post an answer based on the comments we had, but I am afraid if that would be related to the question at all.

Comment: Well, I don't want to bring these two sections because in reality Parabrahma is one. And Lord Shiva is not the one we think as Shiva. Among Tri dev, the one we think as Lord Shiva is Lord Rudra, Shankar. And Lord Shiva in reality is different and he's the infinite Ocean of spiritual light ever pervading this entire Cosmos. But Parabrahma is beyond Tridev. Because truth is - everything is one with Lord and at the same time, they're different!

Comment: That's true. But my point is, we should not get stuck in belief system but rather try to realize the absolute truth knowledge. One who realizes absolute truth would know the hidden knowledge in Shaivsm and Vaishnavism. There is hidden knowledge in that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, certainly. But NOT in the same sense as of those of say, Lord Vishnu or Lord Shiva.
The reason for this is that the nature of the  Parambramhm (Parbramha) is fundamentally different from that of both - ordinary souls like us, who are linked to casual ( and ultimately to gross ) bodies, as well as the divine souls residing in the higher realms.

In particular,

- The gross forms which we refer to as incarnations, exist as material personifications of the divine beings ( read Gods ), who in spite of there divinity, are incomplete aspects of the Supreme Brahma, just like us ( except when they are in yoga with the Consciousness , of course ) .
- There incarnations are therefore  aspects of and by extension casual incarnations of Parbramha.
- Being the 'casual actor' responsible for the the apparent existence of the worlds and beings, it is clearly absurd to speak of there being a personification of the Brahma in one gross body more than in any other, with the possible exception of the divine beings and their incarnations.

All the above points have been sufficiently reconfirmed by both sages and scriptures, for there to be any need for a citation.

**TL;DR**

Clearly, it is impossible to find a scriptural reference to an avatar of the kind you enquired about ( not TOO sure about this ) . However, it is true that these exist and that we are among them.

Comment: Please include the citations if you can. That would help.

Answer (score 5):

Do not be confused about Parabrahma and Vishnu. Parabrahma is Vishnu. Parabrahma is Shiva. Parabrahma is everything. Every deity is a representation of Parabrahma.

**Narayana Upanishad:**

> **Brahmanyo devakiputro brahmanyo madhusudanom**
>
>
> Brahman is Devaki's son, Brahman is Madhusudana.

**Rudra Hridaya Upanishad:**

> Thus everybody should prostrate to Sri Maha Vishnu with great devotion. He is the Atman. He is the Paramatman. He is the Antaratman. Brahma is the Antaratman. Shiva is the Paramatman. Vishnu is the Eternal Atman of all this universe. This whole creation of Svarga, Martya and Patala Lokas is a big tree. Vishnu is the top portion (branches) of this tree. Brahma is the stem. The root is Lord Shiva.
>
> The effect is Vishnu. The action is Brahma. The cause is Shiva. For the benefit of the worlds. Rudra has taken these three forms.
>
> Rudra is Dharma. Vishnu is the world. Brahma is Knowledge. Therefore, do Kirtan of His name, 'Rudra', 'Rudra'. By singing like this, the hallowed name of this great Lord, all your sins will be destroyed.

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted. So the anwer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Rama Lord Krishna are nothing but the avatars of parbrhma itself.

Lord Vishnu Shiva these are different forms of same parbrahma only and when parbarhma incarnates in earth then he took avatar as ram krishna etc.

Thats why when krishna told arjuna about his opulences then he told all the qualities to arjun as his quality which is same as qualities of parbrahm in chapter 10.

In chapter 10, the opulences of parbrahma is described by krishna concluding as it his opulences only and on chapter 10 verse 37, he concluded that among vrishnis(yadavas), i am vaasudeva(krishna).

Comment: Chapter 10 of Bhagavad-gītā? Better to directly quote the verse and its translation. You can find the translation [here](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-37/).