# Why we are here

Tags: shiva

In this world everything temporary,  not only things, human beings, other beings but also world itself,  why do we born and die, die and born.  What's this universal structure,  why this entire universe being controlled by lord **Siva**

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26063/647

Comment: I think basically you are asking (in different words) - what is the need for creation? Then we already have such questions .. like this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/what-is-the-need-of-creation/13990#13990

Comment: "What's this universal structure, why this entire universe being controlled by lord Siva" uhm no, are you a Shaiva? This depends on the sect you are part of.