# Why do Atma and Parmatma split if they are one after all?

Tags: advaita, atma, creation, spirituality, cosmology

As per Advaita philosophy, the ultimate goal of an Atma is to merge into its source, the Parmatma just like drops of water merge into the ocean but my question is how and why do Atma and Parmatma split in the first place?

Comment: It's all Parmatma will. It's his svabhava to manifest from one form to many. Read this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26072/647

Comment: The answer given is totally unsatisfactory FRIENDS like this one thing wanted to be known supreme that is why it split first this nirguna nirajajara why does it have the desire in first place I'm already second to none why I want myself to be known like that @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: This is lightning bolt question

Comment: @Prasanna That "why" is already covered in the answer. Read the shloka and translation at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @Prasanna Let's take a simple example, one person is richest person, will he keep money saved in bank or he will think of a way to invest in some business to make more. Of course he will invest to make more. Same way Parmatma from his freedom of will and action which is infinite, manifest into multiple to experience his own power and to see how powerful he is. That's what is explained in the answer.

Comment: In your richest person example many things are involved at least 2things are there one is money and the person here only one thing is there there is no second @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Prasanna Just like a richest person has power of money, similarly parmatma has power of infinite will and action using which he himself manifests into this whole universe.

Comment: if power is a guna but he is nirguna he cannot express.  is your  god is Idi Amin Dada where he is power hungry want show himself supreme.. is this not regressful..@TheLittleNaruto

Comment: They never split. It is only appears to those in Maya that they have split. You can't 'split' infinity. See the shāntipātha (peace chant) at the beginning of the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad

Comment: So @TheLittleNaruto you mean to say that God has created lower being just to prove he's highest?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda with due respect for your spritual journey if he is unsplitable than we have to agree that before creation there many different things existed along with GOD.. otherwise this creation cannot be done with maya also. as he is unsplittable according to brindaranya upanishad your avaidya that is maya is true in one sense that is changing world.. entaglement of jivas in neverending real world in this many things already existed..

Comment: If brahman is affected by avidhya then why he is brahman? It's like god is affected by disease of his creation then why he is god @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: I read in Shiv Puran that Parbrahman wanted to split itself that is why it assumed the form of Shiva who created Vishnu who created Brahma so could this be the reason for Atmas too?

Answer (score 2):

Did they even split? The split is only an illusion. A must read is the story of two birds in kathopanishad. Therewere no two birds! That was an illusion or dream or whatever..... Advaita vedanta doesnt say you must merge into god! It says you are god! You dont have to reach to a destination. You were always there!!!
So there is no split and it is only maya or adhyasa that makes us feel that there is a split.

Comment: Why maya? is an illeagal question. Because of maya only there is this "why" or causation! You cant ask why to creator of causation.

Comment: So, what is the goal of life if not to merge with God and break the cycle of rebirths?