# is Kashmir Shaivism/Shakti advaita logically coherent?

Tags: shivadvaita

The premises of these two schools (Kashmir Shaivism and Sri Vidya and kaula shaktism) are essentially the same: the infinite, omniscient, omnipotent, perfect consciousness limits itself to become the opposite of these attributes, though pre-eternally.

But aren't these traits inherent to Shiva/Tripura Sundari/Kali/whatever you call the supposed supreme reality? If they are accidental they can be lost, but if the divine is essentially both limited and unlimited, etc(I don't see how this doesn't break the law of the excluded middle and law of identity)then it can never reach Liberation because it is essentially limited too.

How can the essentially necessary supreme have accidental qualities anyway?

Any Advaitists who are not Shankaradvaitists (they have a whole different ontology and metaphysics)have any answers?

Comment: Because it's play of Parmatma. Read this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26072/647

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto me being a Smartha(who follows the path of Sri-Vidya) is a Bhakti Marg, but in its essence is Advaita, states in the words of Om Swami Ji ,"You(the Divine Mother) are my object of worship. You are superior than I am and that is why I’m praying to you. But, I’m not merely interested in eulogizing or seeking pardon for my sins. I want to purify myself to the extent where I merge in you and you merge in me, so that one day I become you. I’m not interested in this union after I die; I want to experience it while I live! "

Comment: @Ramachandra See the above prayer in itself is self contradictory because it starts with supeririy of Divine mother, The suddenly the jiva wants himself or herself to be as superior as divine mother or in other divine mother herself. If you are running store you have employed sales boy, sales boys says to you that i should open a same store in fornt of your store, what you will do you will kick him out.. because buisness is competitive. Just to think of same experience as diving mother in itself is not balsphamey to your bakthi.. Advaitain upsena is dangerous there is no way getting bakthi

Comment: @PrasannaR Ji Have you ever met someone who claims to have had direct darshan of Devi and Bhagavan Shree Krishna.I have met 2 such people one my Gurudeva and other is Om Swami Ji.My Gurudeva since birth for nearly 20 years did intense Sadhana while Om Swami Ji did both Sri-Vidya upasanas and Kundalini Meditations for 20+ years in the Himalayas.They cried for the Devi and Lord Krishna like a little children, begging them to give them a darshan, and then they came, and showed them the Absolute Reality, How they permeate every molecule of this world !

Comment: @PrasannaR Both my Gurudeva in their journey for Truth came across people where 99% were interested in ego-massaging their superiority of bookish and scriptural knowledge with no practical sadhana experience....and others doing sadhana just to attain siddhis.Nobody is interested to meet the Bhagavan and know his true nature,everyone is busy proving his philosophy is superior....Full of ego,anger,jealously and contempt while doing bhakti of the Lord which is just opposite of what bhakti preaches? To be so immersed in Lord meditating that in the end we end up becoming like him?

Comment: @PrassanaR Ji In the end if we don't end up reaching our 'sadhya'-Bhagavan I.e don't become more kind,blissful,compassionate,grateful,truthful then what use of our Sadhana?What use of reading any scripture?

Comment: @PrassanaR both my Gurudevas discovered their truth and received divine Darshana of both Devi and Lord Krishna? So what's your next plan? Will you discover your own truth or remain confined in the superiority complex of one-sided interpreted scriptural knowledge?

Comment: Superiority complex of philosophy no way just take this prayer i become you having the same experience as the lord or devi herself is wrong.. just to think of it is blasphemous to me. if your gurudevs have darshan of the lord is well and good.. but we need to analyse and accept what is being said, take buddha avataar even though he is avaataar his followers teaching not accepted by all hindus.. same hold good for gurus.. there are many people who had darshan of the lord but their understanding of the concept of god is wrong..@Ramachandra

Comment: @PrasannaR Ji Well If you do not even accept the authority of Guru's who have had direct darshana in physical form of the divine and say they are wrong, then i am utterly out of words to convince you out of your ignorance! But as a fellow sadhaka i sincerely wish and request you to do practical sadhana as much as possible so that both of us, despite our philosophical differences, attain the final destination of divine darshana in our own ways as in the end it is only Bhagavan/Devi who know the Truth and can liberate us from this material world!

Comment: think of 2nd or 3rd generation followers who can only have your gurus teaching as guide  but before accepting we need to thoroughly analysis the teachings. what is meant by each sentence he is saying. if become divine. then who is guru? i should not worship my guru. according to this philosophical teaching. simple question if you become krishna yourself at one point of time who is rukmini devi and lashmi devi to you, is it not blashphame.. think before you accept any philosphy @Ramachandra

Comment: @PrasannaR ji becoming one means one who realizes the Bhagavan is the essence of all that pervades this cosmos including me.knowledge has been passed down through bonafide Shakta Tantric and Natha Sampradya tradition....The only reason why you get a divine darshan is because the Devi has accepted your knowledge and devition as true and complete.Thourough analysis based on what may i ask?Scriptures or sectarian translations or maybe on biased personal view?Think based on what? Common sense or scriptures?Which scriptures?Pls don't start a debate of Sattvic VS Tamasic Puranas now.....

Comment: @PrasannaR Both my Gurus are 2nd and 3rd gen followers of their lineage of siddhas who also got the darshana and thus guided my Gurus on the right path.How is their knowledge wrong if it leads to the final goal then and inline with scriptures of Shakta and Natha Sampradaya? Just because your ego says some philosophy is wrong dosen't make it wrong....Infact the only reason majority of people don't experience a darshana because till they end they just cannot abandon their ego,which says my religion/philosophy  is the only way,others are all wrong.

Comment: @PrasannaR All the "most religious people" Both my Gurus came across on their journey were the most rigid ones,unable to abandon their ego,their pre-conceived notions, unable to accept their philosophy might not be the only correct one,always criticising  others, insulting philosophies propounded by Great Saints.....