# What kind of experiences does god want to share?

Tags: vedanta, brahma, creation

I have read  in HSE that God created this world to share His experiences. However not everyone gets the same experience. Some are rich while others are poor. Some are happy while others are sad. There is so much of imbalance .If so, what kind of experience does God want us to share? Why only good experiences can't be shared?

Comment: If possible , please provide the link from HSE , that says  God created this world to share all His experiences.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an exegesis of God  creating creation because he was (in some sense at least) lonely.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26066 @Athrey